# Why does NET::FTP upload files so slowly

Tags: perl, ftp

My problem is about using perl to ftp a local file to the ftp server. The question is why the upload speed is so slow. Here is code:

```
use strict;
use warning;

use NET::FTP;

my $ftpserver = "10.110.143.9";
my $usr       = "John";
my $passwd    = "John";

sub main {
    my $ftp = Net::FTP->new( $ftpserver, Timeout => 200 ) or print "Can't connect ftpserver" sleep 5;
    my $rc = $ftp->login( $usr, $passwd );
    unless ($rc) {
        print("login failed!");
        return 1;
    }
    print("login success");
    $ftp->binary();
    $ftp->put("d:\\2012.txt");
    $ftp->quit;
    return 0;
}
```

Upload times for 30mb are about 5 minutes while using another ftp client on the same machine  takes only 10 seconds or so.

Comment: How fast you can upload same file using some another FTP client? Is it possible that connection to your FTP server is really that bad?

Comment: for example ,the file is about 30MB,using my program is about 5 minutes to upload it to the server，while using another way to upload is ,just about 10 seconds.

Comment: There are two modes of ftp; usually if you do have your ftp client on a publicly addressable IP address which is not 10.x.x.x or 192.168.x.x  you would be able to use active mode. If not you'll want to use passive mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should enable `PassiveMode`, and also play with `BlockSize` (it used to be a source for slowdown with `Net::FTP`), something like this:

```
my $ftp = new Net::FTP(
    $ftpserver,
    Timeout => 200,
    Passive => 1,
    BlockSize => 8192,
);
```

Try increasing (or decreasing) `BlockSize` by factor of 2 few times and see if it changes anything.

Comment: thanks ,I'v Tried to increasing the BlockSize ,when the BlockSize is large,then the upload speed is faster then before.

Comment: Glad it helped you. But I agree that `Net::FTP` quality in general is a bit questionable - it should be able to saturate your connection without any tweaks, like most other FTP clients can do.